# How does one merge the outputs of pandas dataframe value_counts

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

How does one merge the outputs of pandas dataframe value_counts?

I have a pandas dataframe with 100+ columns. If I perform:

```
$ #df = dataframe with 100+ columns

$ df_names_all = df.name.value_counts()
$ df_names_all 
# notice: name and value only
output:
Bob   100
Sally 200
Rufus 300

# then apply a filter condition
$ df_filtered = df.loc[(df.some_column == some_value)]

$ df_names_filtered = df_filtered.name.value_counts()
$ df_names_filtered 
#notice name and value only
output:
Bob   50
Sally 60
Rufus 80

Problem #1:
If I merge or join df_names_all and df_names_filtered, I get a result that is 100+ columns of 'not what I wanted'

Problem #2:
**What I want** is one dataframe with three columns
output:
Bob   100 50
Sally 200 60
Rufus 300 80
```

**How can I merge the two outputs with preferably 1 line of code and achieve the above result?** Also, I really need the outputs disconnected from the original dataset so that I don't incorporate 100+ columns into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the initial `value_counts` a dataframe like so:

```
$ df_names_all= pd.DataFrame(df.name.value_counts())
```

Then when you do the second, make it a column of the frame above:

```
$ df_names_all['Filtered'] = df.loc[(df.some_column == some_value)].value_counts()
```